# "Still" versus "Yet"

Tags: adverbs

In the following sentence, is using of *yet* correct?

> Inserts settlement in a duty that needs it, in the most suitable *yet* available place.

It seems to me that I must use *still* instead of *yet* but at the same time the sentence with *still* does not sound right.

Comment: Do you mean "Most suitable place that is available at this time" or "the most suitable place that is also available"?

Comment: I don't understand the first part of the sentence, myself: "Inserts settlement in a duty that needs it"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use "still", you have to say

> ... in the most suitable place still available.

You can't use the adverb *still* (unlike *very*) on an adjective that precedes the noun. So not

> *I am looking for a still available apartment,

but one of:

> I am looking for an available apartment,
>   I am looking for an apartment that is still available.

Comment: As for point #2, could you hyphenate it? "I am looking for a still-available apartment." That could be used in this context: "_I know there were many apartments available last month; I'm looking for a still-available apartment_." (It's not necessarily how I would pose the question, but your answer got me curious.)

Comment: @J.R. I don't think it's grammatical even when hyphenated. I can't find any grammar discussions on the web about this, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is '.. the most suitable place available at that time'.
There isn't a way to simply imply that a more available place may come to exist appear in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can't substitute "still" because "yet" as it used there has a similar meaning to "but."

"Yet" is also used to mean surprising contrast.

She is gentle yet assertive.

Comment: I thought so too, but what would the sentence mean then? "Most suitable but still available?" As opposed to normally suitable and unavailable?

Comment: Hi SF! It sounds a bit like non-native English. I suppose by "most suitable yet available" they mean a place might be suitable but when you get around to checking its availability, it can't be engaged. Probably written in the context of highly-in-demand facilities?